# How do I execute the result of a query using the psql client?

Tags: postgresql, psql

Using the psql client version 8.4.20, I created this select command that generates a bunch of other select commands:

```
mydatabase=# select concat('select count(*) from ', table_schema, '.', table_name, ';') from information_schema.tables where table_name like '%stockindex_alias%';

select count(*) from de_de.merged_stockindex_alias_de_de;
select count(*) from en_us.merged_stockindex_alias_en_us;
select count(*) from es_la.merged_stockindex_alias_es_la;
select count(*) from fr_fr.merged_stockindex_alias_fr_fr;
select count(*) from nl_nl.merged_stockindex_alias_nl_nl;
select count(*) from pt_br.merged_stockindex_alias_pt_br;
select count(*) from zh_hk.merged_stockindex_alias_zh_hk;
```

I know I can use \g to store those seven statements into a file, then execute the file with \i.

How can I execute the result of the query (those seven statements) in a single command without the intermediate file?  I've tried \set, EXECUTE, searched the web, but can't get it right.

EDIT: The previous select statements erroneously had the word "table" in them, which I have fixed.

Comment: You've already mentioned the way to do it. You're going to need a tempfile.

Comment: Version 8.4.20 is too old and unsupported by now. Do you meat 9.4? Also *executing* is simple, the question is what and how do you want as result *exactly* ?

Comment: @CraigRinger : Yes, I can use a tempfile; it just seemed like there ought to be a way to execute the result of a query in one shot.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter : I want a single command that generates, then executes the seven "select" statements, giving me the counts of those seven tables.

Comment: Spool the output of the first select into a file, then run that generated SQL script using the `\i` command.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : yes, I mention in the question that I know how to do this.  I'm wondering if there's a way to avoid the intermediate file.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it works in 8.4; it works in 9.2.

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    x text;
BEGIN
    FOR x IN (select concat('select count(*) from ', table_schema, '.', table_name, ';') from information_schema.tables where table_name like '%stockindex_alias%' LOOP
        EXECUTE x;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$;
```

Basically you create an anonymous function block and execute it. Function blocks (or whatever the correct name is) allow for variable declaration and dynamic execution.

Comment: The `table` keyword cannot be used in a `SELECT` statement, so this won't work. Also, according to the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-do.html), *the code block is treated as though it were the body of a function with no parameters, returning void* so you cannot easily pass anything out of the code block, unless you use `RAISE NOTICE` or `NOTIFY`.

Comment: Inclusion of the `table` keyword was an error and has been corrected in the edit.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get by with an approximate count, you can use the system catalogs:

```
SELECT s.nspname AS locale, c.reltuples AS count
FROM pg_class c
JOIN pg_namespace s ON s.oid = c.relnamespace
WHERE c.relname LIKE '%stockindex_alias%';
```

This will be most accurate immediately after a `VACUUM ANALYZE` (assuming you are a superuser or own all the affected tables) and gradually reducing in accuracy as the affected tables are modified.